# Using FileProvider cache-path for gmail attachment shows "invalid" error

Tags: android, gmail, android-fileprovider

I would like to send a text file, stored in the app's internal cache, via gmail or some other email app. I've added FileProvider to give one-time permission access to the file.

When I run my app on a device with Android 5.0, it works. When I run it on a device with 6.0, it fails. One failure is an exception:

> No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND
>   flg=0x3 clip={null T:Log file attached.} (has extras) }

This happens when I omit `intent.setDataAndType (uri, "text/plain")`.

The other failure, if I do include the statement above, is an error from gmail. It shows the attachment file name with a graphic that leads me to believe it accessed it properly. It also shows, in the "to" line, the path for the attachment - essentially the uri, but missing the "file:" prefix. If I try to send the message, it gives me an error message: "The address is invalid." If I remove this bogus address from the "to" line, I can successfully send the message, with the attachment.

In other words, my usage of FileProvider, including the various "setup" files, appears to be working. I obviously have something wrong, someplace, perhaps in the Intent usage. Here's my code - the latter version with the bogus "to" address.

Manifest:

```
  <application
    ...
    <provider
      android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
      android:authorities="com.myapp.file_access"
      android:grantUriPermissions="true"
      android:exported="false">
        <meta-data
          android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
          android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
    </provider>
  </application>
```

filepaths.xml (in res/xml directory):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
  <cache-path path="./" name="files" />
</paths>
```

code to create intent:

```
  public static void sendFile (Context context, String path)
  {
    File file = new File (path);
    Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile (context, "com.myapp.file_access", file);

    Intent intent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.putExtra (Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"you@gmail.com"});
    intent.putExtra (Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "your file");
    intent.putExtra (Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    intent.putExtra (Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "file attached.");
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
    intent.setDataAndType (uri, "text/plain");
    context.startActivity (intent);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether is answer is still available after 9 months.

1. data type should be "message/rfc822"
2. gmail's attachment only available when the file is on the external storage "mnt/card/{your_file_path}", for any other file path, gmail/inbox application doesnt recognized